# Build C Library from makefile for ios and not macos

Tags: ios, c, xcode, makefile

I have a makefile that builds some C files and if I run it on an M1 mac the resulting library has the architecture `arm64` which I thought it what is necessary for them to compile with an Xcode project for iOS. I discovered I can run the command `otool -l libf2c.a | grep platform` which should tell me what it was compiled for and in my case it returns `platform1` which indicates macOS. [Based on this](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/b10d445307a0f3c7e5522836b4331090aacaf349/llvm/include/llvm/BinaryFormat/MachO.h#L490), I think I need a value of `platform2` for iOS.

The reason this is an issue is because in Xcode I get the error `ld: building for iOS, but linking in object file built for macOS, file '/Users/e.../close.o' for architecture arm64`.

Based on what I have been researching it seems iOS and macOS have the same architecture (arm64) but are a different 'platform'? But, I am not sure how the platform is determined. Is there some setting in my makefile I need to specify the platform? I am assuming that if I am able to get the platform to be iOS then Xcode will cooperate and be able to build the library I have generated.

Comment: Some history ... Originally, macs were Motorota mc68000, then powerPC, then intel x86. Only recently have they become arm64 (for the M1/M2 platforms). So, you'll need a bit more to deduce what platform you're on. In any event, when building for iOS, you probably shouldn't rely on the _native_ compiler (even if it's arm) but be looking for the cross development tools for iOS/iPhone/iPad. That's because if you have a native arm64 compiler, it will be targeting the M1/M2 chips, which are _mostly_ arm, but have extra special stuff for the M1/M2 which aren't in the iPhone/iPad CPU chips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred way to compile for iOS via command line would probably be to use the `xcrun` command. This will allow you to specify the correct SDK for the platform you actually want to run on. For example:

```
prompt$ xcrun --sdk iphoneos --toolchain iphoneos clang -c test.c -o test.o -arch arm64
prompt$ otool -v -l test.o | grep platform
 platform IOS
```

TL;DR: change your compiler invocation from plain `clang` to `xcrun --sdk iphoneos --toolchain iphoneos clang`.